# Can Nokogiri search for "?xml-stylesheet" tags?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need to parse for an XML style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/templates/xslt/inspections/disclaimer_en.xsl"?>
```

Using Nokogiri I tried:

```
doc.search("?xml-stylesheet").first['href']
```

but I get the error:

```
`on_error': unexpected '?' after '' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri cannot search for tags that are XML processing instructions. You may access them like this:

```
doc.children[0]
```

Comment: -1 This does not work for me on Nokogiri 1.5.5: `p Nokogiri.XML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Foo />').children[0] #=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x323df0 name="Foo">`

Comment: It really worked two years ago, but Nokogiri could be changed from the inside. I tested my code, of course, at the moment of writing this answer.

Comment: I truly believe you. I struggle internally on what to do with old answers to questions that were clearly correct once, but that are no longer valid. My current belief is that such answers ought to be downvoted when an alternative correct answer exists. It's not my intention to punish you (certainly not!) but to show that the answer is (no longer) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an XML element; this is an XML ["Processing Instruction"](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi). That is why you could not find it with your query. To find it you want:

```ruby
# Find the first xml-stylesheet PI
xss = doc.at_xpath('//processing-instruction("xml-stylesheet")')

# Find every xml-stylesheet PI
xsss = doc.xpath('//processing-instruction("xml-stylesheet")')
```

Seen in action:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
xml = <<ENDXML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/templates/disclaimer_en.xsl"?>
  <root>Hi Mom!</root>
ENDXML
doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml)
xss = doc.at_xpath('//processing-instruction("xml-stylesheet")')
puts xss.name     #=> xml-stylesheet
puts xss.content  #=> type="text/xsl" href="/templates/disclaimer_en.xsl"
```

Since a Processing Instruction is not an Element, it does not have attributes; you cannot, for example, ask for `xss['type']` or `xss['href']`; you will need to parse the content as an element if you wish this. One way to do this is:

```ruby
class Nokogiri::XML::ProcessingInstruction
  def to_element
    document.parse("<#{name} #{content}/>")
  end
end

p xss.to_element['href'] #=> "/templates/disclaimer_en.xsl"
```

*Note that there exists [a bug](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/755) in Nokogiri or libxml2 which will cause the [XML Declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl) to appear in the document as a [Processing Instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) if there is at least one character (can be a space) before `<?xml`. This is why in the above we search specifically for processing instructions with the name `xml-stylesheet`.*

**Edit**: The XPath expression `processing-instruction()[name()="foo"]` is equivalent to the expression `processing-instruction("foo")`. As described in the [XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests):

> *The `processing-instruction()` test may have an argument that is Literal; in this case, it is true for any processing instruction that has a name equal to the value of the Literal.*

I've edited the answer above to use the shorter format.

Comment: Note that if you know that each PI is at the root of the document--not a child of another element somewhere deep in the document--you can make your search far more performant by using `xpath('/processing-instruction("xml-stylesheet")`.