# How to retrieve the nokogiri processing instruction attributes?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am parsing the XML using Nokogiri.

I am able to retrieve the stylesheets. But not the attributes of each stylesheet.

```
1.9.2p320 :112 >style = xml.xpath('//processing-instruction("xml-stylesheet")').first
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::ProcessingInstruction:0x5459b2e name="xml-stylesheet">
style.name
=> "xml-stylesheet"
style.content
=> "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"CDA.xsl\""
```

Is there any easy way to get the type, href attributes values?

OR

Only way is to parse the content(style.content) of the processing instruction ?

Comment: It would help if you'd include a short sample of the XML you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by following instruction in below answer.

[Can Nokogiri search for "?xml-stylesheet" tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542264/can-nokogiri-search-for-xml-stylesheet-tags#answer-12223360)

Added new to_element method to Nokogiri::XML::ProcessingInstruction class

```
 class Nokogiri::XML::ProcessingInstruction
   def to_element
     document.parse("<#{name} #{content}/>")
   end
 end

 style = xml.xpath('//processing-instruction("xml-stylesheet")').first
 element = style.to_element
```

To retrieve the href attribute value

```
 element.attribute('href').value
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot you do that?

```
style.content.attribute['type'] # or attr['type'] I am not sure
style.content.attribute['href'] # or attr['href'] I am not sure
```

Check this question [How to access attributes using Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901241/how-to-access-attributes-using-nokogiri) .

Comment: This give me undefined method attribute or attr for String error.