# Ruby regular expression to extract key values

Tags: ruby, regex

I have string like below

```
case1:
str = "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl\""
case2:
str = "href=\"http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl\" type=\"text/xsl\""
```

I need to extract the values like

```
 type -> text/xsl
 href -> http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl
```

Here is my regular expression that fails.

```
 str.match(/type="(.*)"/)[1]
 #this works in second case
 =>"text/xsl"

 str.match(/http="(.*)"/)[1]
 #this works in first case
 =>"http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl"
```

In failure cases the whole string is matched.

Any idea?

Comment: It looks like you are parsing XML. Generally it is a good idea to use a library designed for that purpose. Is there a particular reason you can't or won't do that?

Comment: Yes. I am using Nokogiri. But Nokogiri only gives string for stylsheet  nodes. So that only I am looking for regular expression.

Comment: Nokogiri does everything, not only css.

Comment: @oldergod Could you please take a look at this question. So that you can understand the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066231/how-to-retrieve-the-nokogiri-processing-instruction-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with John Watts comment. Use something like nokogiri to parse XML - it is a breeze. If you still want to stick with regex parsing you could do something like:

```
str.split(' ').map{ |part| part.match( /(.+)="(.+)"/ )[1..2] }
```

and you will get results as below:

```
> str = "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl\""
 => "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl\"" 

> str2 = "href=\"http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl\" type=\"text/xsl\""
 => "href=\"http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl\" type=\"text/xsl\"" 

> str.split(' ').map{ |part| part.match( /(.+)="(.+)"/ )[1..2] }
 => [["type", "text/xsl"], ["href", "http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl"]] 

> str2.split(' ').map{ |part| part.match( /(.+)="(.+)"/ )[1..2] }
 => [["href", "http://skdjf.sdjhshf/CDA0000=.xsl"], ["type", "text/xsl"]]
```

that you can put in a hash or wherever wou want to have it.

With nokogiri you can get hold of a node and then do something like `node['href']` in your case. Probably much easier.

Comment: I solved this by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542264/can-nokogiri-search-for-xml-stylesheet-tags#answer-12223360. Thanks for the quick reply.